# Jaxb - umarshaling mixed xml element with value

Tags: jaxb

I have the follwoing xml element:

```
<FIELD1><COMP VAR="A">text B</COMP> inner text <COMP VAR="B">text B</COMP></FIELD1>
```

How to annotate this property with JAXB:

```
protected List<Object> compOrValue;
```

to have a list of COMP xml elemnts and String values.

Is it possible with JAXB?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of @XmlAnyElement and @XmlMixed to achieve this:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlMixed;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="FIELD1")
public class Root {

    protected List<Object> compOrValue;

    @XmlAnyElement
    @XmlMixed
    public List<Object> getCompOrValue() {
        return compOrValue;
    }

    public void setCompOrValue(List<Object> compOrValue) {
        this.compOrValue = compOrValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of @XmlAnyElement I use @XmlElementRefs({@XmlElementRef(name="COMP", type=COMP.class)}). It wokrs as expected. Thnaks.